# Script executed in Jenkins after commit from repo

Tags: java, svn, jenkins

I am new with Jenkins and I can't find answer for something. I use SVN as my file repository and Jenkins for CI.

The question: is it possible to execute my own script/trigger or sth in Jenkins after SvN commit on commited project? This script would change one file in this project.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: So you do not want the build to happen is it? You just want that script to trigger? If you are building on every commit then you can add pre build steps

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't want to build the project, I just want to execute script on the project which change one file. Is it possible?

Comment: This seems odd... why would you want a post-svn hook to change a file?

Comment: I don't want to use post-commit hook. I want to do it in Jenkins not at svn level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

1. In your Jenkins project -> Conifgure -> Build Triggers
2. Check the box poll SCM
3. In the schedule use the cron expression '*****' This will ensure that jenkins project is build on every commit.
4. Go to Build Environment section
5. Select Configure M2 Extra Build Steps
6. Click on add-pre build step. On clicking you would get option asking if you wish to runn Shell script or windows batch script.
7. Provide the script details and save the configuration and check

**JENKINS is a build tool. In case you wish to perform actions post commit you would have to write a Post-Commit hook for SVN or whichever SCm tool you are using**